# Capture auto-complete from bash in go

Tags: bash, go, autocomplete, stdout, stdin

I am trying to write a wrapper around bash so I can record input, output as well as decorate the standard in/out.

I am using `exec.Command("bash")` and using `cmd.Stdin` and `cmd.Stdout` to interact from the go application with the bash process but I don't know how to handle the auto-completion from bash.

**How do I send the `<TAB>` to bash and get back the updated input line / output?**

Ideally, I would want to be able to run a unit test that would look like that:

```golang
shell := capture.NewShell("~")
out := shell.In([]byte(`cd Docum<TAB>`))
assert.Equal(t, "cd Documents", string(out))
```

Any help, guidance or link to relevant documentation would be super appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Just use `\t` instead of the tabulator?

Comment: That can helps https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tabexpansion.html